# How to display seismic lines from CSV?

Tags: qgis-2

I wish to display land seismic lines on a map. Land seismic lines are often not straight so often there is survey data for each shotpoint or every 5 shotpoints. Typically a shotpoint (SP) could be 25m or 50m apart. There are often many hundreds of SPs. The TDL loads as discrete points. I need to be able to identify the seismic line (that is in the TDL file) and also say every 100 SP.

I cannot find a way to label SPs every 100 points, or to just label the line at the start and end.

A typical file looks like:

```
Rad PROFIL_ID   SP  SWRF99TM_N  SWRF99TM_E  
1   MC-81-313E  4   6414971 735192  6414387 1687468  
2   MC-81-313E  5   6414988 735192  6414404 1687468
3   MC-81-313E  6   6415004 735192  6414420 1687468
4   MC-81-313E  7   6415020 735192  6414436 1687468
```

PROFIL_ID = Line number, SP is Shotpoint and the other 2 columns are XY coordinates.

Comment: Can you add more info on your table? What does "Rad" mean?

Comment: Not sure what Rad means - it is just some sequential number by the file creator and is not relevant.

Answer (score 7):

Is this what you want to achieve (at least for your sample data)?

[image]

The `shotpoints` layer is labeled with this expression:

[image]

The `seismic_line` layer is generated by the `Points to Path` plugin:

[image]

using the following parameters:

[image]

The generated attribute table for this layer is bellow:

[image]

and the layer is labeled using this expression:

[image]

Of course, when you have a long seismic line with hundreds of points, you could label the first layer like this:

```sql
CASE WHEN Sp = 1 THEN 'Start' ELSE '' END ||
CASE WHEN Sp = 100 THEN '100' ELSE '' END ||
CASE WHEN Sp = 200 THEN '200' ELSE '' END ||
.....
CASE WHEN Sp = 999 THEN 'End' ELSE '' END
```

I've showed you this technique to help you easily identify the seismic lines, not only with discrete points, but also with lines.

---

**EDIT**:

The last code could be simplified using the modulo operator, as showed [Spießbürger](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/12729/spiessburger) in his answer:

```sql
CASE WHEN Sp = 1 THEN 'Start' ELSE '' END ||
CASE WHEN Sp % 100 = 0 THEN Sp ELSE '' END ||
CASE WHEN Sp = 999 THEN 'End' ELSE '' END
```

Comment: Nice: The last piece of code could be simplified by using the modulo operator?

Comment: You are right, this code could be simplified using the modulo operator, as you already showed in your response! Good point!

Comment: Thanks very much - it looks a neat solution and I will give it a go.

Comment: Sorin, I have been using your suggested method for display. However, when I now use Points to Path converter the input data headers, e.g. Profil_ID, SP, etc are converted to Group, begin, end. This means I do not see the information you mention when writing the expression, e.g. CASE WHEN Sp = 1 THEN 'Start' ELSE '' END ||. Has something happened in the upgrades to Points to Path? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Labeling the beginning of the line can be done by only labelling when the shotpoint-number is 1. This can be done in the "layer-preferces --> labelling --> and pressing the epsilon at the very top" and entering:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN 'SP' = 1 THEN 'PROFIL_ID' 
END
```

You can also use a similar argument to find every 100th point with the modulo operator (%). The modulo operator will give you the integer rest of a division (110/100 is 1 and 10 rest and therefore not zero, 100/100 is 1 and 0 rest, therefore label it):

```sql
CASE
    WHEN "SP" = 1 OR "SP" % 100 = 0 THEN  "PROFIL_ID" 
END
```

Finding the highest number is probably more complicated.